Экспортирование проекта в Godot 3.5.3 в .apk
Я начал создавать небольшую игру в Godot 3.5.5, решил проверить как в неё получиться поиграть на телефоне. Попытался экспортировать - и ничего не вышло. Пол интернета просмотрел в поисках ответа, так и не нашёл. Пробовал скачать Android Studio и сделать как все говорят, но у меня с ним проблема что он почему то не скачивает SDK, папок в системе после удаление AS нет.
И можно ли вообще экспортировать игру не имея AS, или существуют какие нибудь уже готовые SDK файлы? Заранее спасибо.
